# Redux: using thunk middleware and combineReducers introduces extra key to getState

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

Problem: When using `thunk` middleware before introducing `Redux.combineReducers`, the `getState` passed to the thunk correctly returns an object with the correct keys. After refactoring to use `Redux.combineReducers`, the `getState` passed to the thunk now returns an object with nested keys. See code below which (hopefully) illustrates my point. This could lead to a potential maintenance nightmare of having to constantly grab the correct key for any `thunk` method that accesses state.

Question: Is there a simple way to set the correct context key within the `thunk`? The code feels brittle when I combine reducers and have to insert keys to access the correct state. Am I missing something simple?

Before code:

```
const Redux = require('redux'),
    Thunk = require('redux-thunk');

// this is an action generator that returns a function and is handled by thunk
const doSomethingWithFoo = function() {
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
        // here we're trying to get state.fooValue
        const fooValue = getState().fooValue;
        dispatch({ type: "DO_SOMETHING", fooValue });
    }
};
// this is a simple action generator that returns a plain action object
const doSimpleAction = function(value) {
    // we simply pass the value to the action. 
    // we don't have to worry about the state's context at all.
    // combineReducers() handles setting the context for us.
    return { type: "SIMPLE_ACTION", value };
}

const fooReducer(state, action) {
    // this code doesn't really matter
    ...
}

const applyMiddleware = Redux.applyMiddleware(Thunk)(Redux.createStore);
const fooStore = applyMiddleware(fooReducer);
```

After code (introducing a more global appStore):

```
// need to rewrite my thunk now because getState returns different state shape
const doSomethingWithFoo = function() {
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
        // here we're trying to get state.fooValue, but the shape is different
        const fooValue = getState().foo.fooValue;
        dispatch({ type: "DO_SOMETHING", fooValue });
    }
};


const appReducers = Redux.combineReducers({
    foo: fooReducer,
    bar: barReducer,
});
const appStore = applyMiddleware(appReducers);
```

Comment: I don't *think* this has anything to do with thunk middleware.  It is just a by-product of having more than one reducer and then using `combinerReducers`.  What exactly is the `doSomethingWithFoo`?   Is it an action or part of a component?

Comment: You can see [in the combineReducers function](https://github.com/rackt/redux/blob/master/src/utils/combineReducers.js#L121-L124) that it is expecting the previous state to be attached to the key provided.

Comment: Yea, `thunk` middleware doesn't do anything to modify keys. the `getState` passed to the function returned by my action will just naively return whatever the state is. In the `after` version, this now has nested keys. The problem is specific to using `thunk` middleware. My issue is that this becomes a nightmare to maintain `getState` contexts w/in the `thunk` because you'd have to continually update keys. I'll try to edit the post to be more clear.

Comment: I understand your problem. However, I also wonder if using `getState` on a thunk could be considered an anti-pattern because of just that (also keeping in mind that reading state on an action dispatcher is a bit suspicious).

Comment: @E_net4: Yea, you're right. Methinks the answer is to refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking about it some more, I think the answer is to refactor the `doSomethingWithFoo` action generator so that it accepts `fooValue` as a parameter. Then I don't have to worry about state object shape changing.

```
const doSomethingWithFoo(fooValue) {
    return function(dispatch, getState) {
        // now we don't have to worry about the shape of getState()'s result
        dispatch({ type: "DO_SOMETHING", fooValue });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're over-thinking things.  By definition, `store.getState()` returns the entire state, and `combineReducers()` pulls together multiple sub-reducers into a larger object.  Both are working as intended.  You're writing your own application, so you're responsible for how you want to actually organize your state shape and deal with it.  If you feel things are too "brittle" this way, it's up to you to find a good way to structure things, but that's not a problem with Redux.

Also, using `getState()` in an action creator to determine what to do IS an entirely valid approach.  In fact, the [Reducing Boilerplate](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html) section of the Redux docs even does that as a demonstration:

```
export function addTodo(text) {
  // This form is allowed by Redux Thunk middleware
  // described below in “Async Action Creators” section.
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    if (getState().todos.length === 3) {
      // Exit early
      return
    }

    dispatch(addTodoWithoutCheck(text))
  }
}
```

Comment: Yea, you're right. I think the answer is to refactor so I don't rely on getState. Despite it coming from the Redux docs, I don't entirely agree w/ the example quoted in your response. Suppose at some point, I want to nest the .todos reducer under another store key. Then, I'd have to go back and modify all my action generators that key off of `.todos`. If you refactor the quoted example to `addTodo(todos, text)`, you can do away w/ `getState()` from the thunk. I could be wrong, but I feel that would be easier to maintain.

Comment: Complementing what's been said, the reducers can be remodeled so that the checks are performed in reduction time (i.e. `todos.length === 0`), thus avoiding a read on the action creator.

Comment: Unless the thunk represents a piece of high-level logic of the program, I would still keep away from using `getState()` in a thunk.

Comment: @E_net4: However, if it's something like a network request that can be avoided if there are already three to-dos cached, then that cannot be outsourced to the reducer. The thunk has to read the state somehow. I can't see any way of avoiding it in a case like that.

Comment: @FighterJet Indeed I also came to the conclusion a while ago that we cannot avoid this pattern in some cases. Makes me wonder if the trending Redux sagas would make a cleaner solution for that use case.